# Microsoft.IdentityModel does not support a B2C issuer with 'tfp' in the URI

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to run the WebApp B2C sample:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C

When I try to login, I get the following error:

`IDX40002: Microsoft.IdentityModel does not support a B2C issuer with 'tfp' in the URI. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/b2c-issuer for details.`

If I edit the `Instance` to `https://myHost.b2clogin.com` I get:

`AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'https://myHost.b2clogin.com/1c2009bb-7e35-4a0e-9f22-xxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authresp' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'c24b0337-0bd9-45ee-8376-xxxxxxxxx'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal. Navigate to https://aka.ms/redirectUriMismatchError to learn more about how to fix this.`

**Edit:**
These are my redirects:
[image]

Comment: Please check the redirect URI given in azure app registration is matching with the one you are requesting. Second error message is clearly saying the same.

Comment: `https://myHost.b2clogin.com/1c2009bb-7e35-4a0e-9f22-xxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authresp` redirect uri?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I found [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/tree/master/apps/web-dotnet-core-oidc-b2cui) article/sample, where the `Microsoft.Identity.UI` framework is replaced with the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI`.
However, with the `https://myDomain.b2clogin.com` url I still get the same error, using the custom domain it works, that's enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I deployed custom policy starter pack via [**IEF Setup App**](https://aka.ms/iefsetup) by entering my Azure B2C tenant name like below:

[image]

When I checked that in Portal, **custom policies** are created successfully like below:

[image]

Now I registered one Azure AD B2C app named **`webapp1`** as below:

[image]

I added **redirect Uri** to the above application like below:  `https://localhost:44316/signin-oidc`

[image]

Now, I followed the **same link** that you mentioned and deployed one sample B2C web application by modifying **`appsettings.json`** file like below:

```json
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://sridevib2c.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "9986e76d-bxx7-4x6x-bxx7-3d8xxxxx9a45",
    "Domain": "sridevib2c.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1A_PASSWORDRESET",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1A_PROFILEEDIT" // Optional profile editing policy
    //"CallbackPath": "/signin/B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN"  // defaults to /signin-oidc
  },
```

**JSON file:**

[image]

When I ran the above web application, it took me to **below web page**:

[image]

After selecting **`Sign Up/In`**, I got the login screen like below:

[image]

When I entered my **credentials**, I logged in to the application successfully like below:

[image]

When I clicked on **`Sign Out`**, it showed me below screen by signing me out:

[image]

Comment: I did the same, except that I have a complex custom policy and not the standard one. Furthermore I have a cutsom `Publisher domain`.

Comment: Could you include your custom policy and the screenshot of redirect URIs that you added in your application?

Comment: I added the screenshots of the redirects. Stackoverflow does not allow to add attachments (zip), cannot add a screenshot, the base+extension+susi.xml are ~2000 lines of code. However, the policy works with the other 10 apps I defined. This is the first time I am using the ModelIdentity.